# Tkinter Binding Multiple Scrollbar's to MouseWheel

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building something that uses multiple scrollbars. This class is actually a wrapper for the tk.ScrollBar and it's used to create scrollable frames. What I want is to be able to set a "default" scroll-container.

Assume 90% of the time someone using the application would want to scroll some frame (Which we will call main_frame), and 10% of the time they would want to scroll a different frame. (normal_frame)

It would make sense to have the mousewheel scroll the normal_frame only when the user was hovering over it with the mouse, but to have the mousewheel scroll the main_frame in all instances except when hovering over normal_frame.

The problem is that whenever you call bind_all upon "`<Enter>`"(ing) the normal_frame, when you "`<Leave>`" it, the main_frame no longer scrolls. Any suggestions?

```
class ScrollThing(object):

    def __init__(self, some_frame, default=False):
        self.default = default
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(some_frame)
        self.view_window = tkinter.Frame(self.canvas)
        #things and stuff to setup scroll bar


    def setup_view_window(self):
        if self.default:
            self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)
        else:
            self.view_window.bind('<Enter>', self.focus_in)
            self.view_window.bind('<Leave>', self.focus_out)

    def focus_in(self, *args):
        del args
        # I'm a seperate ScrollThing from main_frame
        # I don't have access to the other ScrollThing because
        # we are both dynamically created. 
        # I want to save the current bound arguments somehow
        # but .bindtags() returns only MY bindings

        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

    def focus_out(self, *args):
        self.canvas.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta//120)), 'units')
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `winfo_containing` method to figure out which widget is under the cursor, and then scrolling that window? That's how the default bindings work.

Comment: That's essentially what the "Enter" and "Leave" bindings do. Whenever the mouse passes over the given frame, it calls the  method bound to enter, and when it leaves it calls the method bound to leave. I'm asking for a way to scroll one particular frame by default. It already scrolls the widgets under the cursor, I want it to scroll another widget when it leaves even if it is not on the "default" widget.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? It's hard to understand what you're asking. I don't see the reason why you're not just setting the binding once on the whole window rather than changing the bindings to the canvas on enter and leave events.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution involving handing the function and the canvas back to the Master.

```
class Master(object)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Things and stuff
        self.default_scroll = None
```

Then by setting default_scroll to hold the default parameters

```
def setup_view_window(self):
    if self.default:
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

        # HERE
        self.dynamic.stuff.MASTER.default_scroll = [self.canvas, self.on_mousewheel]

    else:
        self.view_window.bind('<Enter>', self.focus_in)
        self.view_window.bind('<Leave>', self.focus_out)
```

You can then access it in the focus_out.

```
def focus_out(self, *args):
    self.canvas.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel)

    # HERE
    if self.dynamic.stuff.MASTER.default_scroll is not None:
        self.dynamic.stuff.MASTER.default_scroll[0].bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.dynamic.stuff.MASTER.default_scroll[1])
```

Although, I would be interested to know if anyone knows of a way to access it in a more concise way, perhaps something in tkinter that lets you see all bound events in the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the simplest solution is to set a variable to be the widget you want to scroll, and then set a global binding to scroll that widget.

For example, your app would initialize the binding like this exactly once:

```
self.root.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scroller)
```

Then, in scroller you scroll the default window:

```
def scroller(self, event):
    self.default_window.yview(...)
```

You can also add the binding to the canvases themselves instead of calling `bind_all` if you prefer. The basic concept still works without having to adjust the bindings on enter/leave events.